# Distribution of cosine of angle between random vectors in $d$-dimensional space

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors

What is the distribution of the cosine of the angle between an arbitrary vector and a vector sampled uniformly from the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions?

I can sample from the distribution (albeit inefficiently): take the first standard basis vector to be the arbitrary vector. Sample from the unit sphere by sampling an isotropic Gaussian and dividing by its norm. Then the first coordinate is distributed as needed.

But I'd like to have this distribution's pdf/cdf. It seems simple enough that it must have been studied before, but I can't find anything.

Comment: WLOG reference vector is the positive $x$-axis, now try sampling in polar and then spherical coordinates to get the idea

Comment: Expanding on @gt6989b's point, for $d\ge3$ this angle famously has support $[0,\,\pi]$ and PDF proportional to $\sin^{d-2}\theta$, and with Beta functions you can show as a sanity check this implies $\Bbb E\cos^2\theta=\frac1d$, i.e. each Cartesian coordinate contributes equally on average to $r^2=\sum_{i=1}^dx_i^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on how to sample uniformly from the sphere in spherical coordinates? It seems to me that being able to sample the angle presupposes that you have the answer to my question.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm familiar with the expected cosine square = $1/d$ result. The pdf result matches my intuition that in high dimensions there is a sharp peak in the pdf at $\pi/2$. It would be great to see a reference or proof of that result.

Comment: To sample in 3D, you can sample in [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) uniformly and independently

Comment: And I still need to go from this distribution over the angle to the distribution over its cosine.

Answer (score 2):

Computing the probability that a randomly oriented vector lies within angle $\gamma$ of a reference direction. (This is probably not the "fastest" way, but it what I had in my notes.)

Observe that
$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & \cdots & x_N\end{bmatrix}$$
is randomly oriented with uniform orientation when
$$x_N ~ N(\mu=0, \sigma=1)$$
resulting in a vector with random length.

To eliminate the length variation we can normalize the vector
$$\mathbf{z} = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{|\mathbf{x}|}$$
which is now uniformly distributed on a unit N-sphere.

---

If $\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{r} \geq \cos \gamma$ then we say that $\mathbf{z}$ lies further than angle $\gamma$ from reference vector $\mathbf{r}$ (assuming $\mathbf{r} is of unit length).

To evaluate $P(\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{r} > \cos \gamma)$ we can arbitrarily select a direction for $\mathbf{r}$ as $\mathbf{z}$ is uniformly distributed.

For convenience we choose:

$$\mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Inserting this into the probability expression:

$$P(\mathbf{z}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix} > \cos \gamma)$$

This can be seen to be equivalent to:

$$P(z_N > \cos \gamma)$$

---

Solving for the distribution of $z_N$:

Let $X_n~N(0,1)$

$$\begin{matrix}Y_1 = X_1 \\ \vdots \\ Y_{N-1} = X_{N-1} \\ Y_N = \frac{X_N}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2}}\end{matrix}$$

Note: $Y_N$ is distributed the same way as $z_N$.

Calculating the Jacobian:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{X_1X_N}{[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2]^{3/2}} & \cdots & & -\frac{X_1X_{N-1}}{[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2]^{3/2}} & \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2}{[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2]^{3/2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $J$ is of the form:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{I} & 0 \\
\mathbf{a} & b \end{bmatrix}$$

the determinant is easily evaluated:

$$|J| = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2}{[\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i^2]^{3/2}}$$

Now to solve for the distribution of $Y_N$.

$$f_y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|J|}f_x(\mathbf{x})\,d\mathbf{x}$$

where

$$f_x(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{I=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2_i}{2}} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2}$$

Writing the distribution in terms of $y$:

$$f_y(y_N) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{[\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2 + \frac{Y^2_N}{1-y^2_N}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2]^{3/2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-y^2_N}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} \,dy_1 \cdots \,dy_{N-1}$$

$$f_y(y_N) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-y^2_N)^{3/2}} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-y^2_N}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} \,dy_1 \cdots \,dy_{N-1}$$

$$f_y(y_N) = \frac{1}{(1-y^2_N)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-y^2_N}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i^2} \,dy_1 \cdots \,dy_{N-1}$$

Now we can make a substitution to remove $y_N$ from inside the integral.

Let $u_n = (1-y^2_N)^{-1/2}y_n$

$$f_y(y_N) = \frac{1}{(1-y^2_N)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}} (1-y^2_N)^{N/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} u_i^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} u_i^2} \,du_1 \cdots \,du_{N-1}$$

$$f_y(y_N) = (1-y^2_N)^{(N-3)/2} (2\pi)^{-N/2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} u_i^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} u_i^2} \,du_1 \cdots \,du_{N-1}$$

The integral can be seen to be a constant so:

$$f_y(y_N) = k_N(1-y^2_N)^\frac{N-3}{2}$$

or for notational convenience:

$$f_N(y) = k_N(1-y^2)^\frac{N-3}{2}$$

Since $f_N(y)$ is a PDF and is defined for $0\leq y \leq 1$:

$$\int_{0}^{1} k_N(1-y^2)^\frac{N-3}{2} \,dy = 1$$

$$k_N = \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1} (1-y^2)^\frac{N-3}{2} \,dy}$$

For $N > 1$:

$$k_N = \frac{2\Gamma(\frac{N}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{N-1}{2})}$$

---

The CDF I came up with is below, but I'll skip my derivation.

For N even:

Let $m=\frac{N-2}{2}$

$$F_N(y) = k_N\left[ \frac{\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(m+1)\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos y\right) + y\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} \frac{\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(r+1)}{(2r+1)\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(r+\frac{1}{2})}(1-y^2)^\frac{2r+1}{2} \right]$$

For N odd:

Let $m=\frac{N-3}{2}$

$$F_N(y) = k_N\left[ y\sum_{r=0}^{m} \frac{\Gamma(r+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(m+1)}{(2m+1)\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})}(1-y^2)^r \right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau$ be the cosine of the angle between an arbitrary $d$-dimensional vector and a vector chosen uniformly at random from the unit sphere. Then the probability density function of $\tau \in [-1, 1]$ is proportional to $f_\tau(t) = (1-t^2)^\frac{d-3}{2}$.

A commenter noted that the angle $\theta$ has pdf proportional to $\sin^{d-2} \theta$. (If anyone has a reference for this or proof, please comment and I will amend the answer. I have confidence in it because I drew samples from it and verified that the distribution is empirically correct.) Using this fact, a change of variables from $\theta$ to $\tau$ yields the result.

Comment: I have a proof for it, unfortunately I don't have a reference and its too long for a comment.  I had it as a Word document, but its too old to open with the lates version of Word so I'm stuck with just scanned notes.  I'll see about adding it as an answer, but I don't want to steal the priority of your response.